# Update a dataframe in pandas while iterating row by row

Tags: python, pandas, updates, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this (its a pretty big one)

```
           date      exer exp     ifor         mat  
1092  2014-03-17  American   M  528.205  2014-04-19 
1093  2014-03-17  American   M  528.205  2014-04-19 
1094  2014-03-17  American   M  528.205  2014-04-19 
1095  2014-03-17  American   M  528.205  2014-04-19    
1096  2014-03-17  American   M  528.205  2014-05-17
```

now I would like to iterate row by row and as I go through each row, the value of `ifor`
in each row can change depending on some conditions and I need to lookup another dataframe.

Now, how do I update this as I iterate.
Tried a few things none of them worked.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if <something>:
        row['ifor'] = x
    else:
        row['ifor'] = y

    df.ix[i]['ifor'] = x
```

None of these approaches seem to work. I don't see the values updated in the dataframe.

Comment: I think you want `df.ix[i,'ifor']`. `df.ix[i]['ifor']` is problematic because it is chained indexing (which isn't reliable in pandas).

Comment: Can you provide the other frame as well as the `<something>`. Whether your code can be vectorized will depend on those things. In general, avoid `iterrows`. In your case, you should *definitely* avoid it since each row will be an `object` dtype `Series`.

Comment: You would be better off creating a boolean mask for your condition, update all those rows and then set the rest to the other value

Comment: [Please do not use iterrows().](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758) It is a blatant enabler of the worst anti-pattern in the history of pandas.

Answer (score 432):

You can use `df.at`:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ifor_val = something
    if <condition>:
        ifor_val = something_else
    df.at[i,'ifor'] = ifor_val
```

For versions before 0.21.0, use `df.set_value`:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ifor_val = something
    if <condition>:
        ifor_val = something_else
    df.set_value(i,'ifor',ifor_val)
```

If you don't need the row values you could simply iterate over the indices of `df`, but I kept the original for-loop in case you need the row value for something not shown here.

Comment: See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html, second bullet: "2.You should never modify something you are iterating over"

Comment: I'm not sure if we read it exactly the same. If you look in my pseudo code I do the modification on the dataframe, not on the value from the iterator. The iterator value is only used for the index of the value/object. What will fail is row['ifor']=some_thing, for the reasons mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: now set_value is also deprectated, and should use .at (or .iat), so my loop looks like this:

for i, row in df.iterrows():
  ifor_val = something
  if <condition>:
    ifor_val = something_else
  df.at[i,'ifor'] = ifor_val

Comment: set_value is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use .at[] or .iat[] accessors instead

Comment: This only works if the index is unique. Otherwise has really odd behavior

Comment: @bscan the original question is for a single, unique indexed dataframe.

Comment: Hi, is there any way I can update the entire row while iterating. Say, I have over 100 column and 
`if condition:
     row[6:] = 0
`

Comment: Hi thanks for explanation. Is there a 'better' more efficient way of doing this? I am facing the same problem and updating the data frame is very inefficient. I have thousands of records that I need to iterate over the modify as per few conditions.

Answer (score 128):

Pandas DataFrame object should be thought of as a Series of Series.  In other words, you should think of it in terms of columns.  The reason why this is important is because when you use `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` you are iterating through rows as Series.  But these are **not** the Series that the data frame is storing and so they are new Series that are created for you while you iterate.  That implies that when you attempt to assign tho them, those edits won't end up reflected in the original data frame.

Ok, now that that is out of the way:  What do we do?

Suggestions prior to this post include:

1. `pd.DataFrame.set_value` is [deprecated as of Pandas version 0.21](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html)
2. `pd.DataFrame.ix` is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix)
3. `pd.DataFrame.loc` is fine but [can work on array indexers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968774/2336654) and you can do better

**My recommendation**
Use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

```
for i in df.index:
    if <something>:
        df.at[i, 'ifor'] = x
    else:
        df.at[i, 'ifor'] = y
```

You can even change this to:

```
for i in df.index:
    df.at[i, 'ifor'] = x if <something> else y
```

---

#### Response to comment

> and what if I need to use the value of the previous row for the if condition?

```
for i in range(1, len(df) + 1):
    j = df.columns.get_loc('ifor')
    if <something>:
        df.iat[i - 1, j] = x
    else:
        df.iat[i - 1, j] = y
```

Comment: and what if I need to use the value of the previous row for the if condition? add a lagged column to the OG df?

Comment: efficiency wise, is your approach better vs adding a lagged column or is the effect negligible for small datasets? (< 10k rows)

Comment: That depends.  I'd go for using a lagged column.  This answer is showing what to do if you must loop.  But if you don't have to loop, then don't.

Comment: Got it, also if it's possible to have your feedback for https://stackoverflow.com/q/51753001/9754169 then it would be awesome :D

Comment: Nice for contrasting .at[] with the older alternatives

Comment: This only works if the index is unique. Otherwise has really odd behavior

Comment: Is there are simpler representations similar to row() that can access the value in the data?  I need to change the value in a row multiple times and repeatatively using $df.at[i, 'ifor']= xxxx$ just have too many typing

Comment: @xappppp consider asking a new question.  That way, you can elaborate on what you mean and a would be answerer can have more than just the room in a comment to answer your question.

Answer (score 74):

A method you can use is [`itertuples()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html?highlight=itertuples#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples), it iterates over DataFrame rows as namedtuples, with index value as first element of the tuple. And it is much much faster compared with `iterrows()`. For `itertuples()`, each `row` contains its `Index` in the DataFrame, and you can use `loc` to set the value.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if <something>:
        df.at[row.Index, 'ifor'] = x
    else:
        df.at[row.Index, 'ifor'] = x

    df.loc[row.Index, 'ifor'] = x
```

Under most cases, `itertuples()` is faster than `iat` or `at`.

Thanks @SantiStSupery, [using `.at` is much faster than `loc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc).

Comment: Since you only point at a precise index, you may think of using .at instead of .loc to improve your performance. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc) for more info on this

Comment: weird think but `df.loc[row.Index, 3] = x` does not work. On the other hand, `df.loc[row.Index, 'ifor'] = x` works !

Answer (score 29):

It's better to use `lambda` functions using `df.apply()` -

```
df["ifor"] = df.apply(lambda x: {value} if {condition} else x["ifor"], axis=1)
```

Comment: this should be the new updated answer. the other ones seem to be from earlier in the decade. Who still uses for loops yikes

Comment: And if the value you wish to add must change on a row-by-row basis, rather than over an entire column at once, how will the above work/be applied?

Comment: @steve that is operating on a row-by-row basis. x is the row (series). Lambda can be any function, so you can have arbitrarily complex behaviour there.

Comment: @iqbal125 is right. This is a one-liner solution. It is okay to break a complex problem into a multiple-step solution, but that is the answer one needs.

Answer (score 24):

You should assign value by `df.ix[i, 'exp']=X` or `df.loc[i, 'exp']=X` instead of `df.ix[i]['ifor'] = x`.

Otherwise you are working on a view, and should get a warming:

`-c:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead`

But certainly, loop probably should better be replaced by some vectorized algorithm to make the full use of `DataFrame` as @Phillip Cloud suggested.

Answer (score 20):

Well, if you are going to iterate anyhow, why don't use the simplest method of all, `df['Column'].values[i]`

```
df['Column'] = ''

for i in range(len(df)):
    df['Column'].values[i] = something/update/new_value
```

Or if you want to compare the new values with old or anything like that, why not store it in a list and then append in the end.

```
mylist, df['Column'] = [], ''

for <condition>:
    mylist.append(something/update/new_value)

df['Column'] = mylist
```

Answer (score 14):

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if <something>:
        df.at[i, 'ifor'] = x
    else:
        df.at[i, 'ifor'] = y
```

Answer (score 2):

List Comprehension could be an option.

```
df['new_column'] = [your_func(x) for x in df['column']]
```

This will iterate over the column df['column'] call the function your_func with the value from df['column'] and assign a value to the row in the new column df['new_column'].

Please, don't forget to create a function.

Answer (score -9):

Increment the MAX number from a column.  For Example :

```
df1 = [sort_ID, Column1,Column2]
print(df1)
```

My output :

```
Sort_ID Column1 Column2
12         a    e
45         b    f
65         c    g
78         d    h
```

---

```
MAX = df1['Sort_ID'].max() #This returns my Max Number
```

Now , I need to create a column in df2 and fill the column values which increments the MAX .

```
Sort_ID Column1 Column2
79      a1       e1
80      b1       f1
81      c1       g1
82      d1       h1
```

---

<sub>Note : df2 will initially contain only the Column1 and Column2 . we need the Sortid column to be created and incremental of the MAX from df1 .</sub>