# Using Lambda Function Pandas to Set Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Could anyone suggest a way answer the same question (see link) but by using  lambda function:
[Update a dataframe in pandas while iterating row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330654/update-a-dataframe-in-pandas-while-iterating-row-by-row)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use `apply` with the parameter `axis=1` to insure the function passed to `apply` is applied to each row.

The referenced question has an answer that uses this loop.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if <something>:
        row['ifor'] = x
    else:
        row['ifor'] = y

    df.ix[i]['ifor'] = x
```

To use a lambda with the same logic

```
df['ifor'] = df.apply(lambda row: x if something else y, axis=1)
```