# Pandas first date condition is met while another condition is active

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a time series of scores. My goal is to detect when the score is larger than a certain threshold `th` and then to find when the score goes back to 0. Is quite easy to find each condition separately

```
dates_1 = score > th
dates_2 = np.sign(score[1:]) == np.sign(score.shift(1).dropna())
```

However, I don't know what's the most pythonic way to override dates_2 so that only dates when an 'active' date_1 has been observed

Perhaps using an auxiliary column 'active' set to 1 whenever `score > th` is True and set it to False when the condition for dates_2 is met. That way I can ask for the change in sign AND `active == True`. However, that approach requires iteration and I'm wondering if there's a vectorized solution to my problem

Any thoughts on how to improve my approach?

Sample data:

```
date         score
2010-01-04   0.0
2010-01-05  -0.3667779798467592
2010-01-06  -1.9641427199568868
2010-01-07  -0.49976215445519134
2010-01-08  -0.7069108074548405
2010-01-11  -1.4624766212523337
2010-01-12  -0.9132777669357441
2010-01-13   0.16204588193577152
2010-01-14   0.958085568609925
2010-01-15   1.4683022129399834
2010-01-19   3.036016680985081
2010-01-20   2.2357911432637345
2010-01-21   2.8827438241030707
2010-01-22   -3.395977874791837
```

#### Expected Output

if th = 0.94

```
date    active
2010-01-04  False
2010-01-05  False
2010-01-06  False
2010-01-07  False
2010-01-08  False
2010-01-11  False
2010-01-12  False
2010-01-13  False
2010-01-14  True
2010-01-15  True
2010-01-19  True
2010-01-20  True
2010-01-21  True
2010-01-22  False
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome given the data in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not Vectorized!

```
def alt_cond(s, th):
    active = False
    for x in s:
        active = [x >= th, x > 0][int(active)]
        yield active

df.assign(A=[*alt_cond(df.score, 0.94)])

          date     score      A
0   2010-01-04  0.000000  False
1   2010-01-05 -0.366778  False
2   2010-01-06 -1.964143  False
3   2010-01-07 -0.499762  False
4   2010-01-08 -0.706911  False
5   2010-01-11 -1.462477  False
6   2010-01-12 -0.913278  False
7   2010-01-13  0.162046  False
8   2010-01-14  0.958086   True
9   2010-01-15  1.468302   True
10  2010-01-19  3.036017   True
11  2010-01-20  2.235791   True
12  2010-01-21  2.882744   True
13  2010-01-22 -3.395978  False
```

---

### Vectorized (Sort Of)

I used Numba to really speed things up.  Still a loop but should be very fast if you can install `numba`

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def alt_cond(s, th):
    active = False
    out = np.zeros(len(s), dtype=np.bool8)
    for i, x in enumerate(s):
        if active:
            if x <= 0:
                active = False
        else:
            if x >= th:
                active = True
        out[i] = active
    return out

df.assign(A=alt_cond(df.score.values, .94))
```

---

### Response to Comment

You can have a dictionary of column names and threshold values and iterate

```
th = {'score': 0.94}

df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([[*alt_cond(df[k], v)] for k, v in th.items()]),
    df.index, [f"{k}_A" for k in th]
))


          date     score  score_A
0   2010-01-04  0.000000    False
1   2010-01-05 -0.366778    False
2   2010-01-06 -1.964143    False
3   2010-01-07 -0.499762    False
4   2010-01-08 -0.706911    False
5   2010-01-11 -1.462477    False
6   2010-01-12 -0.913278    False
7   2010-01-13  0.162046    False
8   2010-01-14  0.958086     True
9   2010-01-15  1.468302     True
10  2010-01-19  3.036017     True
11  2010-01-20  2.235791     True
12  2010-01-21  2.882744     True
13  2010-01-22 -3.395978    False
```

Comment: If ever in NY, beers on me :)

Comment: (-: no worries.  Glad you found it.

Comment: Cleaning up comments.

Comment: Lay it on me. .

Comment: I do have a question now, what if the threshold is not a constant but the value of the corresponding row from column 'bound'?, I should change to if y >= th[i] and make sure I'm passing an array instead of a constant, no?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your data is in a pandas dataframe, and 'date' is your index column. Then this would be the way I'd do it:

```
th = 0.94 # Threshold value
i = df[df.score>th].index[0] # Check the index for the first condition

df[i:][df.score<0].index[0] # Check the index for the second condition, after the index of the first condition
```

So use conditional indexing to find the index for the first condition (`[df.score>th]`), then check for the second condition (`[df.score<0]`), but begin to look from the index found for the first condition (`[i:]`)

Comment: I ran your code and it doesn't do anything to the original input a, can you include your results?

Comment: This can be due to the random data. If none of the data yields a value greater than the threshold value, no output is generated

Comment: I get FutureWarning; 'summary' is deprecated (no idea why this is getting triggered tbh)

Comment: I'm running it multiple times, it still not doing anything. Also why generate random data vs loading the dataframe from the clipboard?

Comment: are you asking me to show my outcomes using your code? Use more than three words please

Comment: How can I 'load the dataframe from the clipboard'? I created random data because I don't feel like manually typing your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well then it comes down to the last two lines of codes, assuming your dataframe is called 'df'. I made an edit to the answer.

Comment: your code generates a datetime as result, not the desired output