# Pandas column containing lists - iterate through each list problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence'],['we', 'like', 'pizza'],['hello', 'world']]})
```

And I want to iterate through the lists in column b and do something like capitalize every letter. I can do something like

```
for row in df['b']:
    row = [i.upper() for i in row]
    print(row)
# ['THIS', 'IS', 'A', 'SENTENCE']
# ['WE', 'LIKE', 'PIZZA']
# ['HELLO', 'WORLD']
```

but it doesn't replace the lists in that column. I thought I was reassigning the row values in the for loop but clearly I am not when I print the dataframe after this:

```
print(df)
#    a                        b
# 0  1  [this, is, a, sentence]
# 1  2        [we, like, pizza]
# 2  3           [hello, world]
```

What is the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: By assigning back to the iterable you're not updating the dataframe, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48951427/9698684). Do something like `df['b'] = [[s.upper() for s in l] for l in df.b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
 df['b'] =  df['b'].apply(lambda x: list(map(str.upper, x)))
 df
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I was looking for apply! Thank you! I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a proper way of doing this, but `df.b = df.b.apply(lambda x: [i.upper() for i in x])` should work.