# How to assign calculations done in a for loop by row to blank columns by index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this (with more rows):

```
   Buy      Sell      acct_stock      usd_account
0  True     False
1  False    True
```

I assigned two numerical values to two variables like so:

```
account = 1000
stock_amount = 0
```

For each row in the df that has the combination of `True AND False`, I want to update columns `acct_stock` and `usd_account` by using the numerical variables to do calculations:

I have come up with the following `FOR` loop:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():


    if (row['Buy'] == True & row['Sell'] == False):
        row['acct_stock'] = (account * 0.02)/row[4]
        row['usd_account'] = account - (stock_amount * 0.02)
```

When I run this the columns `acct_stock and usd_account` do not get updated at all, even for rows where the conditions are met.

What am I doing wrong that the calculations are not being assigned by index to the columns/rows in question and the variables `'account'` and '`stock_amount`' are also being updated continously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of why is didn't work is included in [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), The code you need to look at is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330654/update-a-dataframe-in-pandas-while-iterating-row-by-row)

However keep in mind you need to have those column first before you can set a value

Comment: I figured it out, it was what you mentioned plus I was not using `and` but instead `&`. Thank you

Comment: oh yeah, you can only use and in python, but within df.loc[ ] you'd use &