# How to manipulate values of a dataframe without using column name

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has columns like below:

```
MultiIndex([('Longitude', 'Field1'),
            ('Latitude', 'Field1'),
            ('Name with Name Text', 'Field1'),
            ('Name with Name Text', 'Field2'),
            ('IsPresent', 'Field1')],)
```

A csv example of this would be

[image]

I want to iterate through each row in the data and for each value of field I want to replace certain characters, if they exist. For example, replace 'X' with 'Y'. But I don't want to depend on the column name as it can change. I want to iterate over each value and strip the character. Below iteration has field names so can't use it.

```
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    print(j['Name with Name Text']['Field1'])
```

This question has the answer [Update a dataframe in pandas while iterating row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330654/update-a-dataframe-in-pandas-while-iterating-row-by-row) but it depends on the column name. I would like to have a solution which only depends on values and not based on column name.

Comment: [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column names dynamic by index and use the result as in the solution that you refer to.

A way to get the name by index is use this line:

```
# Import pandas package  
import pandas as pd  
    
# making data frame  
df = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv")  
    
# get column names
col_name_list = list(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `j` is a series. So, you can easily navigate to your preferred column using `iloc`. You don't even need to care whether you have used MultiIndex or not. Hence,

```
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    print(j['Name with Name Text']['Field1'])
```

is equivalent to

```
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    print(j.iloc[2])
```

`2` is used here because it is the third column.

Edit: If you want to iterate through every columns:

```
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    for k in range(len(df1.columns)):
        print(j.iloc[k])
```

Comment: is it possible to see how many columns are there and then iterate over it incrementally iso of hard coding 2?

Comment: Yes, you can get the number of columns from `len(df1.columns)` and insert a for loop to iterate over every columns.
I am editing the answer. You may look at that.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating on the rows, each row is a `Series` that you can also iterate:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for col, value in row.iteritems():
        print(value)
```

If you also want to change the value you can use:

```
df.set_value(i, col, <some_value>)
```