# Can't update value in a dataframe using pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dtype

I'm trying to update columns named 'Stock', 'Regular Price', 'Sale price' of a csv file using pandas library in python. Values for updating the csv is extracted from a website. I used selenium to login into website and enter the required pages, BeautifulSoup to parse the page, json to extract particular values from the parsed webpage. I have successfully extracted the required data, but I can't update the csv file with the extracted values...please help.[there is no traceback or any error, also, program succesfully produced a csv file without any change :(  ]

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
```

other code lines are present in between

```
js=json.loads(reqrdthngs)
for variants in (js[0]["productVariants"]):
    k=js[0]["product"]["productName"]
    skucde=re.findall("\([Code:]+\s([A-Za-z0-9]+)",k)[0]
    df1=pd.read_csv(filename)
    df1.loc[(df1['Parent']==skucde)&(df1['Attribute 1 value(s)']==variants["productVariantDescription"]),'Stock']=variants["productVariantQuantity"]
    df1.loc[(df1['Parent']==skucde),'Sale price']=df.loc[(df['code']==skucde),'discount']
    df1.loc[(df1['Parent']==skucde),'Regular price']=df.loc[(df['code']==skucde),'retail']
df1.to_csv('updated_CSVready_to_import.csv')
print ("Done")
```

Comment: You're not actually updating the dataframe with *df.loc*. Rather, you're just accessing these values without changing anything. For a full working solution it would be helpful to get a sample of your data to see what the DataFrame looks like.

Comment: Look at this, seems like a duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330654/update-a-dataframe-in-pandas-while-iterating-row-by-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

silly me, I solved the problem.....it was a silly mistake.
csv was read as df1 inside the loop; df1 was updated and re-defined with non updated csv

```
df1=pd.read_csv(filename)
js=json.loads(reqrdthngs)
for variants in (js[0]["productVariants"]):
    k=js[0]["product"]["productName"]
    skucde=re.findall("\([Code:]+\s([A-Za-z0-9]+)",k)[0]
    df1.loc[(df1['Parent']==skucde)&(df1['Attribute 1 value(s)']==variants["productVariantDescription"]),'Stock']=variants["productVariantQuantity"]
    df1.loc[(df1['Parent']==skucde),'Sale price']=df.loc[(df['code']==skucde),'discount']
    df1.loc[(df1['Parent']==skucde),'Regular price']=df.loc[(df['code']==skucde),'retail']
df1.to_csv('updated_CSVready_to_import.csv')
print ("Done")
```