# Fastest way to iterate and update dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**PROBLEM:** I have a dataframe showing which assignments students chose to do and what grades they got on them. I am trying to determine **which subsets of assignments were done by the most students and the total points earned** on them. The method I'm using is very slow, so I'm wondering what **the fastest way** is.

My data has this structure:

| STUDENT | ASSIGNMENT1 | ASSIGNMENT2 | ASSIGNMENT3 | ... | ASSIGNMENT20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student1 | 50 | 75 | 100 | ... | 50 |
| Student2 | 75 | 25 | NaN | ... | NaN |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| Student2000 | 100 | 50 | NaN | ... | 50 |

**TARGET OUTPUT:**
For every possible combination of assignments, I'm trying to get the number of completions and the sum of total points earned on each individual assignment by the subset of students who completed that exact assignment combo:

| ASSIGNMENT_COMBO | NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS_WHO_DID_THIS_COMBO | ASSIGNMENT1 TOTAL POINTS | ASSIGNMENT2 TOTAL POINTS | ASSIGNMENT3 TOTAL POINTS | ... | ASSIGNMENT20 TOTAL POINTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Assignment 1, Assignment 2 | 900 | 5000 | 400 | NaN | ... | NaN |
| Assignment 1, Assignment 2, Assignment 3 | 100 | 3000 |  | 500 | ... | NaN |
| Assignment 2, Assignment 3 | 750 | NaN | 7000 | 750 | ... | NaN |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| All possible combos, including any number of assignments |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:** First, I'm using itertools to make my assignment combos and then iterating through the dataframe to classify each student by what combos of assignments they completed:

```
for combo in itertools.product(list_of_assignment_names, repeat=20):
for i, row in starting_data.iterrows():
    ifor = str(combo)
    ifor_val = 'no'
    for item in combo:
        if row[str(item)]>0:
             ifor_val = 'yes'
    starting_data.at[i,ifor] = ifor_val
```

Then, I make a second dataframe (assignmentcombostats) that has each combo as a row to count up the number of students who did each combo:

```
numberofstudents =[]
for combo in assignmentcombostats['combo']:
    column = str(combo)
    number = len(starting_data[starting_data[column] == 'yes'])
    numberofstudents.append(number)
assignmentcombostats['numberofstudents'] = numberofstudents
```

This works, but it is very slow.

**RESOURCES:** I've looked at a few resources -

1. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330654/update-a-dataframe-in-pandas-while-iterating-row-by-row) is what I based my current method on
2. [This page](https://towardsdatascience.com/efficiently-iterating-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-7dd5f9992c01) has ideas for faster iterating, but I'm not sure of the best way to
   solve my problem using vectorization

Comment: Have you tried using any of pandas' native functionality?  `groupby`, etc?  Pandas is inherently columnar and so iterating over its rows is very slow, and  not how pandas is supposed to be used...

Comment: Can you give me a sense how that would work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a go at tidying up [Bryan's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75504313/53341)

- Make a list of all possible combinations
- Iterate over each combination to find the totals and number of students
- Combine the results in to a dataframe

***Setup:*** *(Makes a dataset of 20,000 students and 10 assignments)*

```
import itertools

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Bigger random sample data
def make_data(rows, cols, nans, non_nans):
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  df["student"] = list(range(rows))
  for i in range(1,cols+1):
    a = np.random.randint(low=1-nans, high=non_nans, size=(rows)).clip(0).astype(float)
    a[ a <= 0 ] = np.nan
    df[f"a{i:02}"] = a
  return df

rows = 20000
cols = 10
df = make_data(rows, cols, 50, 50)


# dummy columns, makes aggregates easier
df["students"] = 1
df["combo"] = ""
```

***Transformation:***

```
# create a list of all possible assignment combinations (ignore first and last two)
assignments = df.columns[1:-2].tolist()
combos = []
for r in range(1, len(assignments)+1):
    new_combos = list(itertools.combinations(assignments, r))
    combos += new_combos

# create a list to hold the results
results = list(range(len(combos)))

# ignore the student identifier column
df_source = df.iloc[:, 1:]

# iterate over the combinations and compute the results
for ix, combo in enumerate(combos):

  # filter the dataframe for students who have completed this combo
  df_filter = df.loc[ df[ list(combo) ].notnull().all(axis=1) ]

  # aggregate the results to a single row (sum of the dummy students column counts the rows)
  df_agg = df_filter.groupby("combo", as_index=False).sum().reset_index(drop=True)

  # store the assignment comination in the results
  df_agg["combo"] = ",".join(combo)

  # add the results to the list
  results[ix] = df_agg

# create a new dataframe from the results list
combo_stats_df = pd.concat(results).reset_index(drop = True)
```

In [this demo](https://trinket.io/python3/6caad0ba90) it takes ~6 seconds to return ~1000 rows of results.

For 20 assignments that's ~1,000,000 rows of results, so ~6000 seconds (over 1.5 hours).

Even on my desktop it takes ~2 seconds to process 1,000 combinations, so ~0.5 hours for ~1,000,000 combinations from 20 assignments.

I initially tried to write it without the loop, but the process was killed for using too much memory.  I like the puzzle, it helps me learn, so I'll ponder if there's a way to avoid the loop while staying within memory.